# PKIJS signature and verification don't match

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptojs, pki

Consider the following code

```js
    const data = await Deno.readFile("./README.md");
    const certificate = (await loadPEM("./playground/domain.pem"))[0] as Certificate;
    const privateKey = (await loadPEM("./playground/domain-pkcs8-nocrypt.key", "PRIVATE KEY"))[0] as CryptoKey;

    const signedData = await signData(data.buffer, certificate, privateKey);

    // verify same
    const ok = await signedData.verify({
        signer: 0,
        checkChain: true,
        trustedCerts: [certificate],
        data: data.buffer
    })

    console.log(ok); // false :(

    // verify external signed like this
    // openssl cms -sign -signer domain.pem -inkey domain-pkcs8-nocrypt.key -binary -in README.md -outform der -out signature

    const cms = ContentInfo.fromBER(await Deno.readFile("./playground/signature")) as ContentInfo;
    if (cms.contentType !== ContentInfo.SIGNED_DATA)
        throw new Error("CMS is not Signed Data");

    const signedData1 = new SignedData({ schema: cms.content });

    const ok1 = await signedData1.verify({
        signer: 0,
        checkChain: true,
        trustedCerts: [certificate],
        data: data.buffer
    })

    console.log(ok1); // true
```

In the first part I sign data and then I verify it against loaded certificate and it FAILS

In the second part I load a generated signature with `openssl` with same certificate and private key used in the first part and the verification against the loaded certificate is OK.
So, since verification method is the same in both examples, I guess my signature method has something wrong.
Here is the code for signature creation

```js
export async function signData(data:ArrayBuffer, certificate: Certificate, privateKey: CryptoKey):Promise<SignedData>{
    const cmsSigned = new SignedData({
        encapContentInfo: new EncapsulatedContentInfo({
            eContentType: ContentInfo.DATA,
            //eContent: new ans1js.OctetString({ valueHex: data })
        }),
        signerInfos: [
            new SignerInfo({
                sid: new IssuerAndSerialNumber({
                    issuer: certificate.issuer,
                    serialNumber: certificate.serialNumber
                })
            })
        ],
        certificates: [certificate]
    });

    await cmsSigned.sign(privateKey, 0, "SHA-256", data);
    return cmsSigned;
}
```

Here is how I load certificate and key:

```js
export async function loadPEM(src:string,
    type: PEMType = "CERTIFICATE" ):Promise<PkiObject[] | CryptoKey[]> {
    const buffer = pvtsutils.BufferSourceConverter.toArrayBuffer(await Deno.readFile(src));
    const binary = pvtsutils.Convert.ToBinary(buffer);
    const bers = decodePEM(binary, type);
    const ret = [];
    switch (type) {
      case "CERTIFICATE":
        return bers.map(ber => Certificate.fromBER(ber) as Certificate);
      case "PRIVATE KEY":
        for( const ber of bers) 
            ret.push(await crypto.importKey("pkcs8", ber, {
                name: "RSA-PSS",
                hash: "SHA-256",
                },
                true,
                ["sign"]));
        return ret;
      case "PUBLIC KEY":
        return bers.map(ber => PublicKeyInfo.fromBER(ber) as PublicKeyInfo);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem was the algorithm used while importing the key.
By using RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 it now works:

```js
crypto.importKey("pkcs8", ber, {
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        hash: "SHA-256"
    },
    true,
    ["sign"])
```